# How to print the exception in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to code an app for windows phone 8. I want to print the exception to the screen if I get any. So here is what I am doing:

```
try
            {
               //The code which I want to handle for exception
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorStatus.Text = e.Message + "\n\n" + e.Source + "\n\n" + e.StackTrace;
            }
```

where `ErrorStatus` is my TextBlock.
However, the only line in my catch block is giving me an exception during the runtime. The exception is:

`A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary`

Am I doing something wrong syntactically? I am new to C# programming as well as Windows Phone programming.

Edit:

More details of the exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147024891
Message=Invalid cross-thread access.
Source=System.Windows
InnerException:
```

Comment: Are you executing this code locally on your development machine?

Comment: Ya. I am executing this code locally on my emulator.

Comment: Is this just a basic Windows Phone app created in Visual Studio?

Comment: What do you mean by "basic"?

Comment: Sorry, what steps have you taken to create your Windows Phone 8 app up until this point?

Comment: I created a Windows Phone 8 app developed in Visual C# using the .Net Framework 4.5 by going through the "New project" wizard.

Comment: I am basically trying to send a `HttpWebRequest`. Do these details help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show your message from the UI thread: web calls always callback on a background worker thread. So, you need to call the Dispatcher to get this to run on the UI thread.

Also you can just use `Exception.ToString()` to show the message content as a string. This has the advantage of also showing any nested exceptions inside the one you're handling.

As a temporary measure try:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        ErrorStatus.Text = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

More permanently you should either fix the issue or log it to a file so you aren't catching exceptions which are masking bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to print out your exception message so that you may know where the problem is:

```
try{}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    await new MessageDialog("Error message:\n\n" + ex.message).ShowAsync();
}
```